Modifying values in df by value from another df - by same column name and same value in another column
I have two dataframes derived from my data.
One contains limits:
lim <- structure(list(cpx = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), par_1 = c(5, 10, 
5, 1), par_2 = c(KET = 4.34, HNK = 8.68, NKT = 4.3, DHNK = 0.86
), par_3 = c(KET = 18.24, HNK = 36.21, NKT = 19.22, DHNK = 3.87
)), out.attrs = list(dim = c(4L, 2L), dimnames = list(Var1 = c("Var1=HNK", 
"Var1=KET", "Var1=NKT", "Var1=DHNK"), Var2 = c("Var2=LLOQ", "Var2=ULOQ"
))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

The second contains data from measurement:

data <- structure(list(smp_id = c("aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "bb", 
"bb", "bb", "cc", "cc", "cc", "cc", "dd", "dd", "dd", "dd", "ee", 
"ee", "ee", "ee"), cpx = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"
), par_1 = c(4, 8, 4, 4, 4.5, 83, 6, 0.5, 5.5, 9, 4.5, 0.5, 20, 
13, 18, 0.5, 100, 33, 53, 0.5), par_2 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4.5, 3, 
3, 0.5, 5.5, 3, 3, 0.5, 20, 3, 3, 0.5, 100, 3, 3, 0.5), par_3 = c(4, 
4, 4, 0.4, 4.5, 3, 3, 0.9, 5.5, 3, 3, 2, 20, 3, 3, 4, 100, 3, 
3, 44)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))


Number of parameter columns may vary depending on set.
Also number of cpx values per sample may vary depending on set (but is the same in one set).
I nedd to replace every value from data table that is lower than limit for cpx / parameter pair value from limit table with NA
I figured out how to do it for every cpx value separately.
limm_a <- limm %>% 
  filter(cpx == "A")

data_a <- data %>% 
  filter(cpx == "A") %>%
  mutate(across(matches("par"),
                ~if_else(.x < limm_a[[cur_column()]], NA, .x)
                  ))

I know I can close it in loop over each unique cpx from this set...
But it is not what I like to use.
I've tried some combinations like:
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("par"),
                ~if_else(.x < limm[[cur_column()]][limm$cpx == data$cpx], NA, .x)
                  ))

Tried to put row filtering in different way:
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("par"),
                ~if_else(.x < filter(limm, cpx == .$cpx)[[cur_column()]], NA, .x)
                  ))

But it all fails.
I'm quite new with R and still learning.
I want to do it in more elegant way than using for loop.
br Radek

II think this gets your required result:
Edit: Updated to show NAs where value is less than limit as per requirement
and streamlined the function as it now doesn't need to have 2 statements.
data1 <- data %>%
  left_join(lim, by = "cpx", suffix = c("", "_lim")) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^par_\\d$"), \(x) if_else(x < get(paste0(cur_column(), "_lim" )), NA_real_, x))) %>%
  select(!matches("_lim"))



# A tibble: 20 × 5
   smp_id cpx   par_1  par_2  par_3
   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 aa     A       5     4.34  18.2 
 2 aa     B      10     8.68  36.2 
 3 aa     C       5     4.3   19.2 
 4 aa     D       4     4      3.87
 5 bb     A       5     4.5   18.2 
 6 bb     B      83     8.68  36.2 
 7 bb     C       6     4.3   19.2 
 8 bb     D       1     0.86   3.87
 9 cc     A       5.5   5.5   18.2 
10 cc     B      10     8.68  36.2 
11 cc     C       5     4.3   19.2 
12 cc     D       1     0.86   3.87
13 dd     A      20    20     20   
14 dd     B      13     8.68  36.2 
15 dd     C      18     4.3   19.2 
16 dd     D       1     0.86   4   
17 ee     A     100   100    100   
18 ee     B      33     8.68  36.2 
19 ee     C      53     4.3   19.2 
20 ee     D       1     0.86  44   

Edit: approach using lambda instead of \(x)
data %>%
  left_join(lim, by = "cpx", suffix = c("", "_lim")) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^par_\\d$"), ~if_else(.x < get(paste0(cur_column(), "_lim" )), NA_real_, .x))) %>%
  select(!matches("_lim"))


This is a good approach - only thing is I think you want the no condition of your ifelse() to be NA_real_ rather than limcol

Thanks @SamR. I read the question too quickly...

That is nice.  I'll go with that. Thank you.

I understand how it works, I'm just a bit lost on syntax.
I know what each part of mutate across line do.
But where can I find an explanation of this syntax:
\(x) {code} 
I understand that it is some kind of temporary function definition, but I've never seen it done in that way. I'm more familiar with purr-style lambda. Where to look for documentation for this kind of function definition and its usage?

\(x) is just shorthand for function(x). I have added a solution with ~. (I also simplified the original answer as I had an extra statement there because I originally misinterpreted the question. As you can see the \(x) and ~ versions are nearly identical.)
